# Emacs PDE seems to ignore PERL5LIB environmet variable to use @INC

Tags: ide, configuration-files, perl

I'm using `emacs 26.3` under `FreeBSD 12` environment and try to use PDE. My problem is that in the runtime environment the modules (@INC array) are properly addressed by the `PERL5LIB` variable. But using emacs and PDE or flycheck, flymake the local `PERL5LIB` is ignored. What do I've to do to get the emacs setup running?

**Details:**

For my own `perl5`modules, I've a special place in my home directory `~/lib/perl5`, which is addressed by the enviromnent variable

```
export PERL5LIB=$HOME/lib/perl5
```

by my `bash` shell resource script `.bashrc`. Modules from project directories are soft linked from the project directory into the `perl5` library location. For an example I've a project in `$HOME/project/daisi-lts` with a perl5 module repository in it, under

```
$HOME/project/daisi-lts/lib/perl5/Daisi
```

. It is soft linked by

```
$ ln -s $HOME/project/daisi-lts/lib/perl5/Daisi $HOMElib/perl5/Daisi
$ ls lib/perl5/Daisi/
Common.pm   Parser Progress.pm

$ head lib/perl5/Daisi/Common.pm 
# =====================================================================
# Package Common.pm  utils, dictioaries and constants for the
# daisi backup suite
# =====================================================================
package Daisi::Common;
use v5.20.1;
use strict;
... 
1
```

So the file is present. To test the strange behavoir I've written the following program:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
BEGIN {
    print " --- MODULE PATH --- \n";
    for my $path (@INC) {
        my $status = -e $path ? 'OK' : 'MISSING';
        print "PATH: $path $status\n";
    }
    print " ------- EOF ------- \n\n";
}

END {
    print " --- TEST VERSION --- \n";
    use Daisi::Common;
    my $APP_DICT = Daisi::Common::createAppDict(
        'VERSION 1.0','2020-01-23', 'user@host',  'user');
    Daisi::Common::version($APP_DICT, $0, 1 );
    print " ------- EOF ------- \n\n";
}
```

If try to use the `PDE` for syntax check I get the error!

```
Can't locate Daisi/Common.pm in
@INC (you may need to install the Daisi::Common module) \
(@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.30 \
               /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl \
               /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.30/mach \
               /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.30) at test-inc line 14.\
 BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test-inc line 14.
```

If I using the shell environment everything is fine:

```
$/usr/bin/env perl test-inc 
--- MODULE PATH --- 
PATH: /home/i4w/lib/perl5 OK
PATH: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.30 OK
PATH: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl OK
PATH: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.30/mach OK
PATH: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.30 OK
 ------- EOF ------- 

 --- TEST VERSION --- 
STATUS: INFO INTERNAL
test-inc VERSION: VERSION 1.0 DATE: 2020-01-23 CONTACT: <user> user@host
```

What info do I've to give emacs to get it work?

For the PDE the setup I use following elisp settings:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/lib/emacs/pde")
(load "pde-load")

(require 'flycheck)
(global-flycheck-mode t)
```

**EDIT and some tests after the advice of Stephan:**

It is a little bits scatter over the config variables.

1. The vaue of the perl environment (query in elisp) is empty.

   `(getenv "PERL5LIB") is nil`
2. Setting the shell environment according to [Keith Flower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12229404/3338646)
   *"I think both M-x shell-command and M-x compile execute commands in an inferior shell via call-process."* via elisp

   `(setq shell-file-name (getenv "SHELL"))`

   `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")`

will correct the wrong behavior of PDE Check syntax (C-c s) but not for flycheck.

4. Duplicate explicitly the setup of `PERL5LIB` via elisp:

   `(setenv "PERL5LIB" (concat (getenv "HOME") "/lib/perl5"))`

   will work for the PDE and for flymake, flycheck too.

But why does emacs bypasses/ ignores the user shell settings?

Comment: My crystal ball says you're not starting Emacs from your bash shell but from your graphical environment: see  [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell)

Comment: Hm, that is interesting because `M-! echo $SHELL` gives me  `/usr/local/bin/bash`., and `C-x C-e  (getenv "SHELL")` too. How does the graphical process startup of emacs by pass the the default user shell settings?